# GUI interface development in Python

Tags: software-development, python, gui, gui-builder

I need to build a desktop application with GUI in Python. I'm new in Python, so I don't know if it is possible to make my own designs like in HTML with CSS or should I use a library?

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a a number of choices available, (with some platform variability).

- [tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) comes with python by default on most platforms
- [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) *my personal favorite* Free, Windows/OS-X/Linux - permissive licence *still free even for commercial use,* native look and feel, Open Source.
- [QT](https://www.qt.io/) via one of several bindings - Complicated licence model (free for Open Source Projects but definitely not for commercial). *Note the bindings have their own separate licences but even if you are using permissively licenced bindings the QT licence still applies as well.*
- A large number of [other GUI toolkits](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)
- You can even use [pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) to target both desktop & browser.

Comment: I will check wxPython, to start is just what I needed.

Comment: @Royerem: After running `pip install wxPython` be sure to run `wxDemo` from the command line - it gives you a lot of brilliant starting points.